# C# : Error while accessing the arraylist of form1 by form2

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist

i am writing a programme to access the array list of form 1 in form 2.in following programme i am able to access it but in form 2 the array list (of form 1)that i am accessing is showing blank.what can be the reason for this?
The programme for form1 is as follows:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public  ArrayList hop = new ArrayList();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }      

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hop.Add("2016");
            hop.Add("2015");
            Form2 f = new Form2();
            f.checkedListBox2.Text = this.textBox1.Text;
            f.Show();
        }
    }
```

for form 2 as follows:

```
 public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        ArrayList hop2 = new ArrayList();
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();        
        }
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hop2.Add("2016");
            Form1 fp = new Form1();
           // fp.hop.Add("kite");
            if (hop2[1] == fp.hop[1])
                MessageBox.Show("equal");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("not equal");
        }
    }
```

Comment: You instantiate a new `Form1` in your `Form2_Load`, so that your `ArrayList hop` is never filled with any values (from `button1_Click`)...

Answer (score 1):

Pass your `Form1` to the `Form2` constructor:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public ArrayList hop = new ArrayList();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }      

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hop.Add("2016");
        hop.Add("2015");
        Form2 f = new Form2(this);
        f.checkedListBox2.Text = this.textBox1.Text;
        f.Show();
    }
}
```

Get an instance of your `Form1` in `Form2`:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    ArrayList hop2 = new ArrayList();
    private readonly Form1 m_parentForm;
    public Form2(Form1 parentForm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();        

        m_parentForm = parentForm;
    }
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        hop2.Add("2016");

        if (hop2[1] == m_parentForm.hop[1])
            MessageBox.Show("equal");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("not equal");
    }
}
```

NOTE: Be careful, there is no null-checking or anything.

Comment: its worked..can you please explain me the working/role of `this` in  this ` `Form2 f = new Form2(this);` statement.

Comment: @pranjalkhanduri [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk1507sz.aspx) is the current instance of your class. In this particular case **this** is the reference to `Form1` you need to pass to `Form2`.

Answer (score 1):

Use constructer parameter to pass the value to form2.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public  ArrayList hop = new ArrayList();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }      

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hop.Add("2016");
            hop.Add("2015");
            Form2 f = new Form2(hop);
            f.checkedListBox2.Text = this.textBox1.Text;
            f.Show();
        }
    }
```

Form2 code

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        private ArrayList _hopForm1;
        ArrayList hop2 = new ArrayList();
        public Form2(ArrayList hopForm1)
        {
            InitializeComponent();  
            _hopForm1 = hopForm1
        }
        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            hop2.Add("2016");
            Form1 fp = new Form1();
           // fp.hop.Add("kite");
            if (hop2[1] == _hopForm1[1])
                MessageBox.Show("equal");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("not equal");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please choose the answer most helpful to you as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You should.t create a new `Form1` on `Form2` load. Use `Application.OpenForms` as:

```
private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        hop2.Add("2016");   
         var f1 = (Form1)Application.OpenForms[0];//<--this references Form1  current instance   
        if (hop2[1] == f1.hop[1])
            MessageBox.Show("equal");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("not equal");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ArrayList hop2 = new ArrayList();
```

Should be

```
public ArrayList hop2 = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: You should really add some explanation as to why this should work - you can also add comments in the code itself - in its current form, it does not provide any explanation which can help the rest of the community to understand what you did to solve/answer the question.